# Intellij, html filed not properly formatted

Tags: html, intellij-idea

The html file in my intellij is not formatted correctly, i.e "function" is not all nice and yellow, but instead every text is just plain and white.

I think its still recognized since my program still runs

Comment: Can you please add a screenshot or/and the code

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/2pien

Comment: Try to add type="text/javascript" to the script tag

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/Ytd6S Like this? I get an error